# Defining and storing custom data when working with the Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can it be done? Does Facebook API support defining new custom fields / objects and store their data? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we do not current offer this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done, but rather easily you can set up your own database and store the data there, using FB uids/event ids/page ids etc as your primary keys.

Comment: But then I need to setup my own server for the DB. I thought about an application in which the clients communicate only with Facebook.